# Pagination with header and footer

Tags: html, printing

I want to prepare a print page which must be splitted to A4 pages. And this pages must have a header and footer.

This page increase 3 table. First table is header second table is content third table is footer.

Content must be splitted to second tables (I called it as "content table").

For example:

if content has this rows (we determine content table height=600 before)

```
<tr height="100"><td> row1 </td></tr>
<tr height="300"><td> row2 </td></tr>
<tr height="150"><td> row3 </td></tr>
<tr height="100"><td> row3 </td></tr>
<tr height="250"><td> row3 </td></tr>
```

first 3 row must be in first print page, other 2 row must be in second print page.

Like that :

First print page :

```
< Header table >
</ Header table >
< Context table >
  <tr height="100"><td> row1 </td></tr>
  <tr height="300"><td> row2 </td></tr>
  <tr height="150"><td> row3 </td></tr>
</ Context table >
< Footer table >
</ Footer table >
```

Second print page :

```
< Header table >
</ Header table >
< Context table >
  <tr height="100"><td> row3 </td></tr>
  <tr height="250"><td> row3 </td></tr>
</ Context table >
< Footer table >
</ Footer table >
```

I do it before with using jQuery height() function. I measured all the rows height and compared them with content table height (600). Then i write the print pages after split the rows with `document.write` function.  But it is slow in long pages.

I want to do this again using another better way. How can i do that? I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml

Just use CSS.

For header and footer you can use position: fixed.
Header: top: 0px
Footer: bottom: 0px;

```
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='content'></div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

You add margins to content that match sizes of header/footer, so it won't overwrite.

Comment: i think i can split footer table with this way but i dont want to split it i want to split content table

Comment: I understand it. Thank u very much for your respond. :) I will try it

Comment: Np, should work like this you just need to setup content margins properly and then add H/F outside of content box...

Comment: Unfortunately using this technique it probably won't be possible.

Comment: I tried @Page{ } code to set margin. But it sets it to the body not my content table. Do you have any suggest to me ?

Comment: Maybe try setting positive margins on the body and negative (-) margin on the header, positive on footer?

Comment: No it is not working. When i set positive margins on the body i cant write anything to this spaces. It hops another page.